# Unable to update database in android using SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper. I tried to upgrade the database by adding few insertions into the testdb.db file  then according to instructions on 
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper
I renamed this new file to testdb.db_upgrade_1-2.sql and added to the asset folder in the android app. I changed the database version to 2 in the Databasehandler, but still there is an error as shown in the stacktrace which is as follows

```
I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database testdb.db
W/SQLiteAssetHelper: Upgrading database testdb.db from version 1 to 2...
W/SQLiteAssetHelper: processing upgrade: databases/testdb.db_upgrade_1-2.sql
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "SQLite": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

After this the app crashes.

My asset folder contains both /databases/testdb.db 
and /databases/testdb.db_upgrade_1-2.sql

I'm using sqlite3 on my computer to generate the database file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I renamed this new file to testdb.db_upgrade_1-2.sql

That is incorrect. `testdb.db_upgrade_1-2.sql` is supposed to be a text file containing SQL statements to apply to your schema v1 database to convert it into a schema v2 database.

Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#database-upgrades), with emphasis added:

> Update the initial SQLite database in the project's assets/databases directory with the changes and **create a text file containing all required SQL commands to upgrade the database** from its previous version to it's current version and place it in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I misinterpreted the instructions